# Express server is not connected Kindly help me

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am learning mern stack and was watching a tutorial on youtube code camp.org. I followed along with tutor code but his code is working and mines not working. my express server is not connected or something. I started nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

but i am not  getting the console message which i should get if i am connected to express server.

this is my index.js file

```js
import app from '../server'
import mongodb from "mongodb";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI, {
  poolSize: 50,
  wtimeout: 2500,
  useNewUrlParse: true,
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
.then(async client => {
    app.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log(`listening on  ${port}`)
    })
})
```

and in case you need this is my server.js file

```js
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import restaurants from "./api/restaurants.route.js"

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/restaurants",restaurants)
app.use("*", (req,res)=>res.status(404).json({error: "not found"}))


export default app
```

my specified port is 5000

kindly i am a beginner guide me what should i do

thank you!

Comment: You have the server starter code in `index.js`.

Comment: @prasad_ can you explain a little bit what to change

Comment: Try something like this to start the server: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html